# Amazon EC2 and nagios possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nagios

I'm looking for a stable and non-local solution for my nagios and vpn instances. Is there a way to use these on amazon EC2 cloud ? Can someone point me in the right direction ? Are there possbilities to run a debian or ubuntu VPS on the cloud ?

I've looked at amazon EC2 but it all seems so chaotic to me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. If you choose to use AWS, you'll want to make sure you use an EBS-backed instance so your data stays persistent.

If you wanted something a bit more simple to deploy and manage, I may recommend that you look at a more "traditional" VPS provider like Linode. I'd recommend Slicehost as well, but unfortunately Rackspace is shutting down their Slicehost product soon.

Comment: Will I have some kind of shell access with AWS ? Do you might have an example or a tutorial on AWS, because I don't what they mean with instances :/

Comment: with AWS, you get SSH access to a VM running whatever you want. The main issue is your server isn't guaranteed stable; instances can die periodically for no reason at all. This is why amazon provides monitoring and high-availability layers on top of EC2 (CloudFront). But if you don't want to deal with that (I wouldn't for Nagios) ErikA's "traditional options" are likely a better choice.

Comment: I agree with ErikA, AWS is probably not a good fit for what you are trying to accomplish (from what I can gather from the information you have provided).

*edit* Accidentally hit enter...

Anyway, for much less cost and complexity you could get a VPS from someone like Linode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are official Ubuntu kernels ready for Amazon EC2 and documentation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

Also, if you plan to run a Nagios instance, I suggest you to consider Centreon (http://www.centreon.com/).